# как узнать ширину без учета padding и border в javascript

Tags: javascript, width

Мне нужно узнать ширину блока без учета padding без JQuery при этом это должно указываться только в пикселях и быть числом.

```js
document.body.onload = function() {
alert(document.getElementsByClassName('progressbar').width);
}
```

```css
.progressbar {
  width:20%;
  height:100px;
  padding:10px;
  background:black;
}
.progressbar .progress {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="progressbar">
  <div class="progress"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21064101/understanding-offsetwidth-clientwidth-scrollwidth-and-height-respectively

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Функция [`.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) вернет окончательные значения свойств, применяемые к элементу. При этом все размеры приводятся к пикселям, например `width: 212px` или `font-size: 16px`. Чтобы преобразовать к числу используем [`.parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

```js
var computedStyle = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('test'), null)
var width = parseInt(computedStyle.getPropertyValue('width'));
console.log(width);
```

```css
#test {
  background: #eeeeee;
  border: 1px solid #444444;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 123px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```